# Jquery function preventing website to scroll all the way down

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a fixed header on my website that shrinks on page scroll with this function:

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() > 350) { 
            $('header').addClass('shrink');
        }
        else{
            $('header').removeClass('shrink');
        }
     });
 });
```

When viewing the website on a mobile device, I want to remove the fixed header, leaving it to be just a regular header, so this is what I did:

```
if ($(window).width() < 769) { 
    $('header').removeClass('shrink'); 
}
```

The problem is that now the website won't scroll all the way down on mobile. 
Can anyone help me fix this, please?

Comment: Pass the event and use event.preventDefault()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry... stackoverflow doesn't allow formatting in comment.

Try this...

```
  .shrink { 
    position:fixed; 
    clear:both!important; 
    width:100%; 
    height:50px!important; 
    max-height:50px!important; 
    min-height:50px!important; 
    z-index:999999999; 
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out; 
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out; 
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out; 
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out; 
}

@media screen and (max-width: 769px) {
    .shrink {
       position: static;
    }
}
```

Comment: It worked! :) I did have to do position: static !important; not sure why because I didn't do !important for position fixed, but hey it looks good. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing it in JavaScript why don't you try CSS.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 769px) {
    .shrink {
       /* write your rules here.*/
    }
}
```

You should post your code or URL. I have no idea what's the logic behind remove "shrink" class, from the code you provided, it seems you haven't added that class to the header, but you are removing it.

I think the best solution in your case would be remove the position CSS rule for mobile devices.

Comment: Hi Nesar, I did try to solve it with CSS at first but the screen was glitching on scroll. The CSS I tried was `.shrink {display:none;}`. Anyways, the CSS I have right now is `header.shrink {
  position:fixed;
  clear:both!important;
  width:100%;
  height:50px!important;
  max-height:50px!important;
  min-height:50px!important;
  z-index:999999999;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}`

Comment: try this
  .shrink { 
 position:fixed; 
 clear:both!important; 
 width:100%; 
 height:50px!important; 
 max-height:50px!important; 
 min-height:50px!important; 
 z-index:999999999; 
 transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out; 
 -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out; 
 -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out; 
 -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out; 
  background:blue;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 769px) {
    .shrink {
       position: static;
    background:green;
    }
}